# Highlight exported Go functions

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, highlight, filetype-go

Golang [uses](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3) naming convention to separate functions visibility: exported (public) starts with a capital letter, non-exported (private) with a lower letter. I would like to highlight exported functions, so it would be easier to explore new files and APIs. Here is my try:

```
match Title /func [A-Z][a-z0-9_]*/
```

Is there a way to improve it somehow? For example, right now `func` is highlighted with the name. Is it possible to get rid of it? Maybe someone have better proposals for regex?
Also, how to apply this only for Go?

Comment: try: `match Title /func \zs[A-Z][a-z0-9_]*/`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, yep that did the trick, only the function name is highlighted.

Comment: CamelCase names seem to be allowed in Go, so wouldn't the correct regular expression be `/func [A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]*`? This can then be written more concisely as `/func \u\w*/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To borrow [@Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt)'s answer in the comments (and break it down further):

```
match Title /func \zs[A-Z][a-z0-9_]*/
```

The regex is the same as before, but the `\zs` marker effectively tells Vim, "Here's where the match *starts*." So we can use this to find the word `func`, followed by a space, followed by a valid public Go function name, but we only match from the beginning of the function name.

To add this to only Go files, you have two options.

#### Filetype plugins (preferred)

Drop this in `~/.vim/syntax/go.vim` to overrule go highlighting, or `~/.vim/after/syntax/go.vim` to modify go highlighting:

```
match Title /func \zs[A-Z][a-z0-9_]*/
```

#### Autocommands

Drop this in your `.vimrc`

```
augroup GoFuncHighlight
  au!
  au FileType go match Title /func \zs[A-Z][a-z0-9_]*/
augroup END
```

This way, when a filetype is set to "go", we get the match command run

**Further Reading**

- `:help autocmd`
- `:help FileType`
- `:help filetype`
- `:help syntax`
- `:help \zs`

As @Carpetsmoker states in the comments:

> Note that this won’t work for (exported) receiver methods, which look like `func (f Type) Name()`. In addition unicode identifiers are allowed in Go [...].

Comment: I know grundic used `:match` in their question, but it makes sense to use a `:syntax` command for this, doesn't it? Especially in the case where you're putting it in a `syntax` file.

Comment: @Rich syntax commands aren’t my strong suit off the top of my head, but I’d be happy to update my answer later with an alternate method using syntax commands.

Comment: It turned out to be slightly more complicated than I was expecting. I [wrote my own answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14048/343)

Comment: Note that this won't work for (exported) receiver methods, which look like `func (f Type) Name()`. In addition unicode identifiers are allowed in Go; `func ЛЛЛ()` is a perfectly valid (exported) function name.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker noted. I borrowed the search pattern from the question without much further though.

Comment: Yeah, that's understandable. Just wanted to point out the caveats/limitations  for future readers :-)

Answer (score 3):

David Ben Knoble has already given you a [good, working solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14036/343).

However, seeing as this is syntax that you're highlighting, I feel like it's cleaner to perform the task with a `:syntax` command. This also has the slight advantage that `:match` is free for other purposes.

For reasons [I'm slightly unclear on](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14047/how-does-zs-interact-with-syntax-matches), it's not possible to use the previously explained `\zs` atom in this match, but it's easy to achieve using a syntax pattern offset instead. Drop the following command in the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/go.vim`:

```
syntax match goExportedFunction /func [A-Z][a-z0-9_]*/hs=s+5 contains=goDeclaration
highlight default link goExportedFunction Title
```

This syntax group will take precedence over the existing `goDeclaration` group used for the `func` because it starts in the same position, but was declared later.

The `hs=s+5` after the regular expression tells Vim that you want the highlighting to start 5 characters after the beginning of the match i.e. at the start of the function name.

The `contains=goDeclaration` might not strictly be necessary depending on your colour scheme, but it means that the `func` at the beginning of the line is still matched by the `goDeclaration` group in the same way as before.

N.B. For clarity, I've used the same basic regular expression as you used. However, as I suggested [in a comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14019/highlight-public-go-functions/14048#comment24104_14019), the following is faster, more concise, and more correct:

```
syntax match goExportedFunction /func \u\w*/hs=s+5 contains=goDeclaration
```

#### Further Reading

- `:help :syn-priority`
- `:help :syn-pattern-offset`
- `:help :syn-contains`

Comment: Very nice! Would it be a good idea to integrate to the default go.vim syntax?

Comment: Seems like it would be! But I don't know Go well enough (read: at all) to say definitively that that's the case.

Comment: @grundic If the go.vim maintainer were integrating it into go.vim, there would probably be a cleaner way to achieve the desired effect, though. `:h syn-nextgroup` seems like a better choice, for example.

Comment: I'm trying to understand whether it's already available [here](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/blob/master/syntax/go.vim)?

Comment: From a very brief skim, it doesn't look like it is? But OTOH, I'm no syntax highlighting expert, and it seems more likely that it would be. Installing it would be an easy way to find out!

Comment: Good answer Rich; my only comment would be that I've frequently seen people use syntax highlighting groups and then linked those to Vim's default groups... not sure if that makes sense in this context to use?

Comment: @grundic I use the vim-go plugin and am 80% sure they use a good highlighting rule (can't remember off the top of my head)

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble Whoops! Good catch. I've edited my answer to do this, as it should.

Comment: Note that this won't work for (exported) receiver methods, which look like `func (f Type) Name()`. In addition unicode identifiers are allowed in Go; `func ЛЛЛ()` is a perfectly valid (exported) function name.

Comment: As a vim-go maintainer, I'm not sure about integrating it in vim-go @grundic; I actually took a quick look at this earlier, and it requires some work with contained syntax groups and such, and there are already a whole bunch of knobs/settings which makes it all rather complex. Personally I think this feature is a bit too specific/obscure for adding there, and adding it in your own vimrc file is easy enough.