# How does `\zs` interact with syntax matches?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

Consider the text:

```
foobarbaz
```

First we highlight the regular expression `/foobar/`:

```
:syntax match Special /foobar/
```

[image]

Next we highlight the regular expression `/foobarbaz/`:

```
:syntax match Error /foobarbaz/
```

This match begins in the same position as our `Special` group, but it was defined later, and so it takes precedence. (See [`:help :syn-priority.`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-priority))

[image]

Now let's clear that (`:syntax clear Error`), and instead try starting our highlighting at `bar` by using `\zs` to set the start of the match.

```
:syntax match Error /foo\zsbarbaz/
```

[image]

Okay, that didn't work, but perhaps it's because by altering the start of the match, this match now begins *inside* our earlier group. If that's the case, we can fix it with the [`containedin`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-containedin) argument:

```
:syntax match Error /foo\zsbarbaz/ containedin=Special
```

[image]

That seems to have worked!

Now let's try starting our highlighting from the `baz`:

```
:syntax match Error /foobar\zsbaz/ containedin=Special
```

[image]

Huh. Now that we've moved the start of our `Error` match past the end of the `Special` match, it no longer works. (Note that I'm not using the [`contained`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-contained) argument, so even if the `Error` group  starts outside of the `Special` group, it should still match: removing the `containedin` argument also has no effect.)

The sole mention of `\zs` in `syntax.txt` doesn't appear to be relevant (it regards multi-line patterns), and `:help \zs` also doesn't shed any light on this.

What's going on?

N.B. For this particular example, I could use an `hs` syntax pattern offset to achieve the desired highlighting, and with more complicated regular expressions I could use `\@<=` look-behind. But `\zs` is recommended over `\@<=` for performance reasons, and in any case, I'd still like to understand how the feature *works*.

Comment: Were you ever able to find anything else out about this? This has me very intrigued.

Comment: Maybe the behaviour is implied by "The next char is the first char of the whole match." in pattern.txt, i.e. they don't actually overlap. But that would mean that your last example should work if you leave the `containedin` out! I think it is a bug (documentation, if not otherwise).

Comment: @SakariCajanus `'containedin'` *allows* an item to start inside another group; it does not require it. If there is no overlap, then the last example should work regardless of whether or not `'containedin'` is set.

Comment: Also you need to state the version of the program you are using since this functionality has evolved substantially over the last 25 years.  If you want the authoritative source to: "What exactly is going on here" you'll have to get into the C source and start hacking.  It's all right there, nothing is hidden: github.com/vim/vim

Comment: I can't find the ref now, but I remember discovering that this was because `\zs` still "consumes" (from the point-of-view of the regex engine) the input prior to matching, while lookahead/behinds do *not*

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Hmm. Can you be any more specific about what you mean by “consumed”? How does this explain the difference between the behaviours of the last two regular expressions in the question?

Comment: When the engine “consumes” the text, it doesnt go back and look at it again—even if other things might match there. Its like the text is part of the match, even though we used \zs. I may not be explaining this well, and I havent read your q in detail

Comment: Okay, I understand what you mean, but I don’t *think* it helps explain the behaviour I’m seeing. Let me know if you do get a chance to read my whole question though: maybe I’m missing something obvious!

Comment: Late to the party, but for what its worth, the experience above appears to be a bug. `\zs` does start a match and behaves as expected on gvim for windows, vim terminal in git bash, but not vim for windows command line terminal. \zs and \ze appear to do nothing there. works correctly on ubuntu linux however.. I tested on versions 7.2 to 8.2