# Syntax Highlighting a region inside the start match of another region

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have two syntax region defined as follows:

```
syntax region xBCD start="b" end="d"
hi def link xBCD Todo

syntax region xBlock start="\z(abcde\)\zs::" end=";"
hi def link xBlock Comment
```

and a text file like this:

```
abcde::test;
```

I.e, I have is a syntax region that I'd like to define within the start match of another region.

When I use these regions, then only the `xBCD` region is highlighted.

---

If I try to defined `xBCD` as contained in `xBlock`, like this:

```
syntax region xBCD start="b" end="d" contained
hi def link xBCD Todo

syntax region xBlock start="\z(abcde\)\zs::" end=";" contains=xBCD
hi def link xBlock Comment
```

then I get the opposite effect; everything after `start` is highlighted as `xBlock`, but `bcd` is not highlighted as `xBCD`.

Is there some way to define and highlight other regions within the un-highlighted parts of a broader region's `start` match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The fix

```
syntax region xBCD start="b" end="d"
syntax region xBlock start="abcde::"hs=s+5 end=";" contains=xBCD
```

### Explanation

The problem is not that Vim cannot highlight a subset of `start`. Instead it is your use of `\zs` that is causing issues. We can show this is true by removing the `\zs` and allowing the `xBCD` to be inside the `xBlock`:

```
syntax region xBlock start="abcde::" end=";" contains=xBCD
```

You will see that your `bcd` is now highlighted, but obviously now your *entire* `xBlock` is highlighted, which is not your goal.

Using a highlight offset (see `:help syn-pattern-offset`) fixes this.

Using a "positive lookbehind" instead (see `:help /\@<=`) is an alternative method of achieving your desired highlighting which might work better for your requirements:

```
syntax region xBlock start="\(abcde\)\@<=::" end=";"
```

(Your use of `\z()` to mark the subexpression as "external" doesn't seem to be used anywhere in your example, so I removed it. The solution still works fine with it reinserted, though.)

### Why your code failed

Here is my explanation of I think was going wrong with your code. It's conjecture, but [based on a reasonable amount of experimentation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14047/how-does-zs-interact-with-syntax-matches):

When you use `\zs` it moves the start of your match to *after* the `abcde`. This means that your `xBlock` is no longer the first piece of matching syntax in your sample file: the `xBCD` is now found a few characters earlier, and thus is highlighted. Vim then starts looking after the end of the matching `xBCD`, which is too far forwards for `xBlock` to match, so no more matches are found.

Your attempt to fix it by adding `contains=xBCD` to your `xBlock` definition therefore failed because the `xBCD` region is *not* inside `xBlock`, it's a few characters before the start of where the `xBlock` would be, if its own presence didn't prevent the `xBlock` from being matched at all.

The reason your second attempt gave different results is that you also added `contained` to your definition of `xBCD`, which does *not* mean that `xBCD` can be found inside other syntax groups, but instead that it *cannot* be found outside of them, at the top level. Therefore, the `xBCD` region is no longer found, and now your highlighting for `xBlock` starts working.

I also tried allowing the `xBlock` to start within the `xBCD` block (the opposite of what you tried) with appropriate use of `contains`, because this is closer to how Vim would see it, but that failed too: I guess because regardless of whether Vim considers the `a` or the `:` to be the "start" of the match, neither is actually within the `xBCD` region.

I therefore don't think it's possible to get this working using `\zs`.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is a phenomenal explanation.  My MVCE was not the best, as you pointed out in an earlier edit, but you basically identified the problem which was my use of `\zs`.  I have inherited a syntax file which used them very liberally, but your use of `\@<=` is working perfectly and is exactly what I need, and may solve a host of other problems.  I regret that the bounty has expired but you have my and the vim-rst community's gratitude :).

Comment: @marshall.ward Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think vim can do what you want (highlight region in a start match of another region -- in terms of vim regions)

But you can do simpler thing (in case you didn't find it in a documentation) -- highlight start and end of a region with a different highlight group:

[image]

```
syntax region xBlock matchgroup=String start="abcde::" end=";"
hi link xBlock Todo
```

Comment: Thanks very much for replying.  Unfortunately I do need it to highlight a subset of `start` rather than the whole thing.  (I am in fact already using something similar to this to highlight the `::`).  I'll keep this open a while longer, but I may need to ask this one on the vim_dev mailing list.