# Set Indentation when Declaring Constructors for C++ Classes with Inheritance

Tags: indentation

I've been using vim for two years but there are many things I don't know very well.
Today, I was coding in c++ and found that I wanted to type the snippet like this:

```
Horse(COLOR color, HANDS height, int age):
Animal(age),
itsColor(color),
itsHeight(height) {
    cout << "Horse constructor...\n";
}
```

Instead I found:

```
Horse(COLOR color, HANDS height, int age):
Animal(age),
    itsColor(color),
    itsHeight(height) {
        cout << "Horse constructor...\n";
    }
```

How can I make the closing curly brace to align with the constructor definition?

My vimrc settings are:

```
set secure
set showmode
set number
set relativenumber
set cursorline
set linebreak
set colorcolumn=81
set updatetime=1000
set conceallevel=0
set showbreak=↳
set wrap
set lcs=tab:>-,nbsp:%,trail:¬
set list
set cinoptions=g0,l1,i0
set smarttab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set shiftround
set expandtab
autocmd FileType make setlocal noexpandtab
autocmd FileType markdown setlocal colorcolumn=0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Indent methods

Vim has several indent methods, including

- `'autoindent'`
- `'smartindent'`
- `'cindent'`
- `'indentexpr'`

Each one is unique and differently powerful.

### cindent

According to `:help cino-i`, you want to use `'cindent'`. This is already set for `cpp` files in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent/cpp.vim`, as found by doing `:verbose set cindent?` from a `cpp` file.

#### Customizing cindent for this case

To change the indentation of "C++ base class declarations and constructor initializations," you then want to change `'cinoptions'` to include `i0`.

The example in the help docs:

```
                                                *cino-i*
iN    Indent C++ base class declarations and constructor
      initializations, if they start in a new line (otherwise they
      are aligned at the right side of the ':').
      (default 'shiftwidth').

        cino=                     cino=i0 >
          class MyClass :           class MyClass :
              public BaseClass      public BaseClass
          {}                        {}
          MyClass::MyClass() :      MyClass::MyClass() :
              BaseClass(3)          BaseClass(3)
          {}                        {}
```

In order to accomplish that, I would do the following:

1. Set up a `C++` filetype plugin by creating the the file `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim` (or wherever your vim directory is)
2. Add the following line to it:

   > `setlocal cinoptions=i0`

This works because `'cinoptions'` defaults to an empty string, is not changed by a filetype plugin, and the values used when not provided include `is` (use a `'shiftwidth'`) as seen in the help:

```
cinoptions=>s,e0,n0,f0,{0,}0,^0,L-1,:s,=s,l0,b0,gs,hs,N0,E0,ps,ts,is,+s,
        c3,C0,/0,(2s,us,U0,w0,W0,k0,m0,j0,J0,)20,*70,#0
```

---

#### Caveat based on OP's vimrc (AKA How to enable filetype-settings)

The OP's post already has `cinoptions` with `i0` in it (although it is set globally in all files). However, it does not appear to be working.

In order for this solution (and indeed `cinoptions`/`cindent` in general) to work, you need to enable filetype detection, plugins, and indenting (at the very least). To do this, add the following line to your vimrc:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

You can find some more similar information [on this vi.stackexchange post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15009/vim-never-shows-line-number-for-python-files-even-though-i-have-vimrc/15019#15019) and [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14019/highlight-exported-go-functions/14036#14036) and [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15325/using-tabenter-and-filetype-in-the-same-autocmd/15329#15329).<sup>They're all mine, because they were easy to find and I have written extensively on the topic.</sup>

---

#### Further notes

Some testing related the unfortunate experience that the precise snippet in the OP then becomes

```
Horse(Color color, HANDS height, int age):
Animal(age),
    itsColor(color),
    itsHeight(height) {
        cout << "text" ;
    }
```

which is only a small step towards the solution requested by the OP. This can be corrected by not indenting continuation lines (`+0` for `'cinoptions'`). However, then continuation lines won't be indented (see `:help cino-+`). I suppose these are technically continuations (hence the commas, hence the indent).

The results:

```
class MyClass :
itsColors(color),
Animal(age),
itsHeight(height) {
    cout << "text" ;
}
```

A better solution remains to write and use `indentexpr` (possibly falling back on `cindent()` except in this case). I am not currently up to the task.

Comment: > you need to enable filetype detection, plugins, and indenting

Comment: Yes, as I noted in my answer you need `filetype plugin indent on`

Comment: Sorry, man, I didn't know comments don't format markdown blockquote. I wanted to tell you that I just didn't put all my vimrc in the post. I did have `filetype plugin indent on` in the top. Also, neovim does that by default.

Comment: Oh ok alright np