# Using `TabEnter` and `FileType` in the same `autocmd`

Tags: autocmd, spell-checking

I would like to set `set spell` whenever I open a `tex` file.

My first attempt is

```
autocmd FileType tex setlocal spell
```

I am using `setlocal` here because I may open other files in new tabs after opening a `tex` file and I don't want `spell` in the new files.

This works well, but I notice that if I open another `tex` file in new tab, the `spell` is not enabled.

I tried

```
autocmd TabEnter,FileType tex setlocal spell
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Better idea: ftplugin. Will write a detailed answer later.

Comment: Note that it would be similar to [my answer here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15019/10604)

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble That looks like what I need, will try in out later. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Frame Challenge : Using Vim "Properly"<sup>1</sup>

`autocmd` is *NOT* the solution to `filetype`-dependent settings. It might seem like a good candidate at first, but Vim was built after the Unix philosophy of placing files in defined directory structure to affect behavior. Most vim users learn about vimrc first. But there are more (see `:help rtp`).

What this means for the OP is as follows : Tex `filetype`-dependent settings, mappings, &c. should be placed in

> `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`

E.g., create `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` with the contents

```
setlocal spell
```

to have Tex files get `spell` on. Note I used `setlocal` to make it buffer specific.

If you find that something in these files conflicts with other settings, you should place the offending line in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` to have it override any other settings.

Finally, make sure you at least enable filetype plugins with `filetype plugin on`.

#### Further Resources

- `:help filetype`
- `:help ft-tex-syntax`
- `:help ft-tex-ftplugin`

---

1. I put "properly" in quotes because at times, when speaking about the Vim philosophy, I've been told its powerful configurability means there is no "right" way to use it. I disagree—I admit there are lots of creative ways to use a saw, but it was originally meant to cut things (wood mostly).
2. The original version of this answer came from my own post [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15019/10604). I do not consider them explicit duplicates, however.

Comment: There are those (not me!) who argue that they prefer autocommands because they like to have all their configuration in a single file. It's not a view I subscribe to (`ftplugin` just seems more elegant, and I believe is very slightly more efficient), but I think it's a reasonable position to take.

Comment: Fair enough @Rich —I’d say there are some things autocmds work for (running complex scripts for certain events, e.g.) but for filetype settings, we already have a dedicated mechanism, hence the answers

Answer (score 0):

I've got the desired behavior using

```
autocmd BufReadPre *.tex setlocal spell
```