# How can I use different vim setting for different filename?

Tags: original-vim

In most cases, I want to use the same setting. However, when I write the makefile file, I need to use tab instead of space, so I need to execute the `:set noexpandtab` for all the makefile file. In order to simplify this process, I want to write this to .vimrc, but I don't know how to execute this command according to the name of the file being edited.

Comment: Another option would be to change the syntax file of make files

Answer (score 6):

[As I have written about extensively](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15329/10604), the vim technique for this type of thing is called an `ftplugin`, which stands for filetype-plugin. What that means is that certain filetypes have different settings than others. `make` is one such filetype.

Vim comes with a set of filetype detecters that are enabled when you do

```
:filetype on
```

However, you can ask vim to load any filetype-specific plugin code (which can be arbitrarily awesome!) and indent code with

```
:filetype plugin indent on
```

Most vim users I know have this command in their vimrc.

Finally, the default ftplugin for makefiles sets `noexpandtab`, I believe. If not, you can place

```
setlocal noexpandtab
```

in your personal vim ftplugin for make, which typically lives at `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/make.vim` (though other names are possible). The `setlocal` version makes the change unique to that buffer, which means all make buffers.

---

Why not auto-commands? Because it’s vimrc clutter and because vim already has autocommands that fire on a Filetype—and all they do is source the appropriate runtime files. It’s inelegant not to use this mechanism. It separates out my filetype settings so I can quickly focus on only what I need.

---

Since we're doing "vim proper," I am obligated to also mention `b:undo_ftplugin`—it is `execute`d if the filetype changes, so you generally want it to be properly set. If you don't switch filetypes, no harm done, but to be on the safe side:

```
" Don't forget to add to 'b:undo_ftplugin'
" I've got a specialized framework for that over at
" https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/autoload/ftplugin.vim
" but this is simpler and should work for your purpose
let b:undo_ftplugin = get(b:, 'undo_ftplugin', '')
if ! empty(b:undo_ftplugin)
  let b:undo_ftplugin .= ' | '
endif
let b:undo_ftplugin .= 'setlocal expandtab<'
```

Comment: Do you think you might want to mention `b:undo_ftplugin` in your answer? (Unfortunately that complicates things and is only relevant when you switch filetype of an existing buffer, so not often... But still mentioning might be worth it.)

Comment: @filbranden I'll mention it briefly. Was yours the second upvote? If so, thanks for the 6k ;)

Comment: Congrats! Great milestone! It's a great answer, I was hoping `ftplugin` was going to be mentioned in an answer here, it's definitely the right approach. I'm really glad that it was.

Comment: I've never ever defined `b:undo_ftplugin` in my numerous ftplugins as I've never needed to switch the filetype of my buffers. However, even if I tend to disagree with `b:did_ftplugin` for non-standard ftplugins, it starts to have its use when dealing with settings that are usually set in standard ftplugins like the one for `Makefile`s.

Comment: @LucHermitte sorry, huh? I follow you on undo_ftplugin (though I have in fact needed it before). But for the other... do you mean it’s useful in non-after directories to stop vim’s runtime files? In general, I dont want that; I’d rather override them afterwards then disable them completely, because im customizing. Im just not following why you mentioned it/what you mean. Are there improvements you think could be made?

Comment: My mistake. My remark was more general and not targetted to the specific solution you've proposed with the ftplugin in the `after/` subtree.

Comment: However there is a debate that starts with: _"when shall we override?"_: before or after the default ftplugins are triggered? _Before_ if we want to replace completely the standard settings, in which case `b:did_ftplugin` shall be set. _After_ if we just change one thing like tabexpansion for a given filetype. In the later case we may be tempted to set `b:did_ftplugin` if we follow blindly the help manual, in which case our ftplugin will be disabled automatically by the standard one. Yet, it's interesting to have a guard, specific to the current file, for the reasons explained in the help.

Comment: @LucHermitte agreed; just wasnt following you on the original comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autocmd` for this. First run the following command to know the FileType (while your makefile is open) -

```
:set filetype?
```

This will show you the filetype. Then you can put the following in your `vimrc` to set settings for specifice fitetype like this -

```
augroup makefilesettings
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType makefile setlocal noexpandtab
augroup END
```

Comment: There are better options than auto commands, though I was sure the default ftplugin for make set this

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put this in your .vimrc:

```
if expand('%:t')=="Makefile"
" do your stuff
endif
```

Comment: This won't work. `.vimrc` is loaded only once. When we open other files from the current session (`:edit`, `:sp`...), it isn't reloaded, and the check won't be applied to the new files. The only way that works is to rely on events, and the way that scales consists in using filetypes plugins. Moreover, `Makefile` are already correctly managed (and do what the OP is looking for) as long as ftplugins are activated in the .vimrc as D. Ben Knoble explained.