# Restricting filetype mappings

Tags: vimrc

I have written the following mapping in my vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType python     :iabbrev <buffer> for for item in:<left>
```

After I source the python file it works. However, now whenever I type in `for` in the vimrc file, I get that same iabbrev behavior, even if I re-set `ft=vim` in that file. Why does this abbreviation occur across/outside of files I specify? Is there a way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword is `<buffer>`, not `<filetype>`.

It exactly means what it says: it affects the current buffer. Once the event has been triggered, the mapping exists in the current buffer, and it'll stay *forever*.

If you change the filetype, you'll just trigger another event that may define new things, and maybe override a few that already exist.

If you really plan to change the filetype of the current buffer, definitively use a ftplugin, and at the end fill the [`b:undo_ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#undo_ftplugin) variable with all the things you have defined and that you wish to see undone.

Comment: Were you the one asking me if I really used this var? (Cant remember, genuinely curious)

Comment: @Luc -- when you say "The **Keyword** is" is there a vim-meaning of the word `keyword` or do you mean it more colloquially, like "The important term here is..." ?

Comment: Also for this: `filetype of the current buffer, definitively use a ftplugin`. Would you be able to show the most basic way to create a `ftplugin` with the above command? i.e., where would it go and would I just copy-paste the command in or does it require other stuff?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble. Yes. Your memory is good. I was the one.

Comment: Regarding ftplugin, try the help. Otherwise, see these answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/2153946/15934, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39380769/15934, or if you want examples, I have plenty: https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/tree/master/ftplugin, really plenty https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/tree/master/ftplugin

Comment: @David542 https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22256/10604 https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15329/10604 https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18493/10604 https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15019/10604