# How to stop auto indent for some file with particular suffix

Tags: indentation

In my .vimrc file, I add few lines to it so that some file could have nice auto indent, such as .f90 and  .c file, but it also cause autoindent for .plt file. Is there some way like if statement that could fix the problem such that the
lines are working when I am working on .c or .f90 file and not working when I am working on .plt file?

Comment: `:help ftplugin`

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/set-indentation-when-declaring-constructors-for-c-classes-with-inheritance/

Answer (score 1):

The short answer (since I feel like [I've written plenty about ftplugins before](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15009/vim-never-shows-line-number-for-python-files-even-though-i-have-vimrc/15019#15019)) is to use filetype plugins.

> You need `filetype plugin on` at minimum for this to work.

Create e.g. `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim` and put e.g.

```
setlocal autoindent
```

You can also do this for fortran (`.f90`).

Take out the `autodindent` things from your vimrc, and you should be good to go.

---

I don't recognize the `.plt` extension, and neither does my vim, but you could give it a filetype by doing

```
" ~/.vim/ftdetect/<name>.vim
autocommand BufRead,BufNewFile *.plt set filetype=<name>
```

And then put more filetype-plugin commands in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<name>.vim`.

---

Some might advocate for putting `indent` related settings in `~/.vim/after/indent/<filetype>.vim` (and I would argue they are wrong; see `:help indent-expression`, which says indent files are for setting `'indentexpr'`). If you do so, you'll need `filetype plugin indent on`.