# Unwanted extra indentation of multi-line statements

Tags: vimrc

How can I make continuation lines indent 1 tab instead of align with the some text? With the default cindent options, I get the following:

```
static int A = 0,
           B = 0,
           C = 0;
```

But, what I want is

```
static int A = 0,
    B = 0,
    C = 0;
```

I have gone through all the cino settings, and none of them seem to affect this. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not join first 2 lines.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I prefer to keep them on separate lines because I tend to put comments beside each of the variables.

Comment: I was talking int and `A = 0`, you can still comment besides each variables.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Because of your comment, I have been able to clarify my question.

Comment: C style indentation is really a drag in vim. There are a couple of ways to set up the indentation. But it's all a little too much work to justify the return. I would advise you to use `:h copyindent` and do manual indenting on *some* lines that can't be indented with `copyindent`. And [here is another question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16134/16280) similar to your problem. It might help you understand some basic things.